# JTable renderer for JPanel, panel having text field and button. When I click text field - button getting hidden

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jpanel, renderer

![here with attached two images , first one is ERP application screen shot i am trying]
![to create,second one is erp screen shot which is i want in my swing gui][1]
![this is my swing gui, when i click on jtable cell jbutton(up arrow image)getting hide ] 
![i want  it stable][2]

```
class PlusMinusCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public JTextField l;
    //renderer for jpanel contains jtextfield and jbutton!

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        // below  code for jtextfield have no border
        l = new JTextField(value.toString()) {
            @Override
            public void setBorder(Border border) {
                // No!
            }
            //enter image description here
        };
        //below code jtextfield editable when single click</i>
        DefaultCellEditor singleclick = new DefaultCellEditor(l);
        singleclick.setClickCountToStart(1);
        //set the editor as default on every column </i>
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount() - 1; i++) {
            table.setDefaultEditor(table.getColumnClass(i), singleclick);
        }
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jp.add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        >below code for rendered row that was selected.

                   if (isSelected) {
         //jtable cell is rendered by jpanel it containd jtextfield (l) 
            // and jbutton (k).. when i click on jtable cell , jbutton 
            //should display on that cell, it should clickable 
 }
        {
            int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
            int colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
            System.out.println("hai iou" + rowIndex + colIndex);
            JButton k = new JButton(new ImageIcon("arrowup.png"));
            k.setBorder(null);
            jp.add(k, BorderLayout.EAST);
            k.setVisible(true);
            jp.setVisible(true);
            return jp;

        }
        return jp;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 4) I am not clear from treading the title. What is supposed to happen?  What currently happens?  Explain each case separately.

Comment: DefaultTableCellRenderer extends from JLabel, so it seems a bit pointless to then add a JTextField to it. Creating a JPanel and JTextField for EVERY cell, EVERY time the table is rendered is very inefficient ... Besides, I don't see a JButton anywhere...I'm not quote sure what you expected from the DefaultCellEditor...

Comment: your renderer (or this attempt) is wrong, is there some reason, my answer is not, there isn't any without your detailed description based on your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: can't found some diff between those two linked images then 1st. is addded ...